# 2 SQL requests. Through the buyer of the store to bring the names of other buyers

Tags: mysql, sql, request

1. By the title of the city (through a parametric window), withdraw the names of the most elderly vendors living in this city.

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Years, c.City
FROM Sellers AS s, City AS c, Shops AS sh
WHERE s.Years In (SELECT MAX(Years) FROM Sellers as s, City as c, Shops AS sh
                 WHERE s.CityID = c.CityID
                 AND City = Town AND c.City=Town 
                 AND c.CityID=s.CityID);
```

First request doesn't work right.

2. By the name of the buyer (through a parametric window), withdraw the names of other buyers of its stores.

```
SELECT Name, Shop
FROM Buyers AS b, [Buyers shops] AS bs, Shops AS s
WHERE b.BuyersID = bs.BuyersID AND bs.ShopsID=s.ShopsID;
```

This is SQL communication between tables.
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/77813063/112732441-aa238480-8f42-11eb-96f8-2d8d429f790e.jpg
[enter image description here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/77813063/112732441-aa238480-8f42-11eb-96f8-2d8d429f790e.jpg)

Comment: What's your question about this? If you have any problem, what have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: This looks like two questions.

Comment: You did not ask any question. You have to explain your question clearly; If you have any error when executing the above SQL queries; post the error message as well.

Comment: I tried to apply the post solution below. But he does not work as I would like

Answer (score 0):

Query#1

```
select s.Name, s.Years, c.City
from Sellers as s inner join City as c
          on s.cityid=c.city_id
where years= (select max(years) from sellers as sel where sel.cityid=s.cityid)
```

Query#2
Please use proper join syntax instead of comma(,). This will make the query more readable and easy to modify at later point.

```
SELECT Name, Shop
FROM Buyers AS b inner join [Buyers shops] AS bs
           on b.BuyersID = bs.BuyersID
inner join Shops AS s
           on bs.ShopsID=s.ShopsID;
```

Comment: The first query should take the oldest people by the title of the city. Not all at once. I made the code more readable.

Comment: this query should fo that. Could you share some data llz?.

Comment: https://github.com/AndreyAugust/SQL-Querry Unfortunately your code work not right